# Nested UIView inside UICollectionViewCell not updating

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uikit

I'm trying to display a list of recepcies for at pet proyect, which I've modeled with a `UICollectionView` and for each item, a custom `UICollectionViewCell`.

This `UICollectionViewCell` has inside a `UIImageView` and a custom `UIView` for layout pruposes.

The tree goes like this

```swift
HomeViewController (UIViewController)
└── UICollectionView
    └── RecepieCardCollectionViewCell (UICollectionViewCell)
        ├── UIImageView
        └── RecepieCardInfoView (UIView)
            └── UILabel
```

I'm comforming to the `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocols at the [`HomeViewController`](https://github.com/Oipie/oipie-app-ios/blob/main/Oipie/Home/Infrastructure/UI/HomeViewController.swift), and then I'm configuring the cells and their nested UIViews though a configure method

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
        withReuseIdentifier: RecepieCardCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath
    ) as? RecepieCardCollectionViewCell else {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
        
    cell.configure(self.recepies[indexPath.row])
        
    return cell
}
```

Then, at the `RecepieCardCollectionViewCell`:

```
func configure(_ recepie: Recepie) {
    cardInfoView.configure(recepie)
    thumbnail.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: recepie.getCover()))
}
```

And, finally, at the `RecepieCardInfoView`

```
func configure(_ recepie: Recepie) {
    label.text = recepie.getName()
}
```

The thing is that the most deep nested `UILabel` at the `RecepieCardInfoView`, is receiving the data, but is not being updated. It always shows the same placeholder text, instead of the actual recepie name.

[image: screenshot demonstring the labels not being updated]

Things I've tried:

- Placing `.setNeedsDisplay()` to all the element, with no results.
- Using `DispatchQueue.main.async` but didn't work, which makes sense since I'm not using an API request to show the recepies (for now).
- Move the label inside `RecepieCardInfoView` to the `RecepieCardCollectionViewCell`. This worked for some reason, but I would like to understand why.

If you need more context of the code, you can find the full repository [here](https://github.com/Oipie/oipie-app-ios/tree/feat/recepies-list) at the branch `feat/recepies-list`

I've been asked to add the full code of the cell, here it is:

```swift
import UIKit
import Kingfisher

class RecepieCardCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let identifier = "RecepieCardUICollectionViewCell"
    
    let thumbnail: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: "https://i.imgur.com/ISxVZHA.png"))
        return image
    }()
    
    let content: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 40
        return view
    }()
    
    let cardInfoView = RecepieCardInfoView(frame: .zero)

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        backgroundColor = .themeWhite
        layer.cornerRadius = 40
        
        addSubview(content)
        content.frame = bounds
        content.addSubview(thumbnail)
        
        let cardInfoView = RecepieCardInfoView(frame: .zero)
        
        content.addSubview(cardInfoView)

        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.17
        layer.shadowOffset = .zero
        layer.shadowRadius = 10
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            thumbnail.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: content.leadingAnchor),
            thumbnail.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: content.trailingAnchor),
            thumbnail.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: content.topAnchor),
            thumbnail.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thumbnail.widthAnchor),
            cardInfoView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: content.bottomAnchor, constant: -100),
            cardInfoView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: content.bottomAnchor),
            cardInfoView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: content.leadingAnchor),
            cardInfoView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: content.trailingAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
    
    func configure(_ recepie: Recepie) {
        cardInfoView.configure(recepie)
        thumbnail.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: recepie.getCover()))
    }
}
```

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: Can you add your cell class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create 2 instances of `cardInfoView` inside `RecepieCardCollectionViewCell`

```
let cardInfoView = RecepieCardInfoView(frame: .zero) // here 1

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    backgroundColor = .themeWhite
    layer.cornerRadius = 40
    
    addSubview(content)
    content.frame = bounds
    content.addSubview(thumbnail)
    
    let cardInfoView = RecepieCardInfoView(frame: .zero) // and here 2
```

The problem is that you add the inner view without updating it's content , and update the outer view without adding it to cell hierarchy

Comment: Good find. (voted.) Where is that code? In the link the OP provided?

Comment: @DuncanC yes in github link